# In python how can I get current users SID in Windows?

Tags: python

I need to get the SID of the currently logged on user from a python script.  One option is to read the return text when shelling to a command prompt command whoami /user.  But this is really ugly.  Surely there must be a better way?

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/62639/win32security.LookupAccountSid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around in the programcreek site that Mehrdad mentioned in his comment

I came up with this

```py
# pip install pywin32
import win32security

desc = win32security.GetFileSecurity(
    ".", win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION
)
sid = desc.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner()

# https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/71691/win32security.ConvertSidToStringSid
sidstr = win32security.ConvertSidToStringSid(sid)
print("Sid is", sidstr)
```

Might need some tweaking because I'm just getting the user who owns the current directory.

There's [this](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/9fbc2ed3c0d69aca2475975a599cc316016599d3/win32/Demos/security/query_information.py#L7) example on the pywin32 [github](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/)

```py
from ntsecuritycon import *
import win32api, win32security, winerror

# This is a Python implementation of win32api.GetDomainName()
def GetDomainName():
    try:
        tok = win32security.OpenThreadToken(win32api.GetCurrentThread(),
                                            TOKEN_QUERY, 1)
    except win32api.error as details:
        if details[0] != winerror.ERROR_NO_TOKEN:
            raise
        # attempt to open the process token, since no thread token
        # exists
        tok = win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(),
                                             TOKEN_QUERY)
    sid, attr = win32security.GetTokenInformation(tok, TokenUser)
    win32api.CloseHandle(tok)

    name, dom, typ = win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, sid)
    return dom

if __name__=='__main__':
    print("Domain name is", GetDomainName())
```

Change it by using the `sidstr = win32security.ConvertSidToStringSid(sid)` method.

It's getting the current process's user which is more ideal I think. (I use my system as only one user so I'm sure the first one works for many use cases)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an my example of doing so in Python:

```py
import subprocess
import os

sid = None
out = subprocess.Popen("wmic useraccount get name, sid", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = out.communicate()[0].decode().replace("\r", "")
for line in out.split("\n"):
    if line.startswith(os.getlogin()):
        sid = line.replace(os.getlogin(), "").strip()
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my example by using the `whoami` windows shell command without the need of installing the `win32security` module. I don't believe it looks more ugly than the other solutions ...

```
import subprocess
    
cmd = 'whoami /User'
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
sid = output.decode().split('\r\n')[6].split(' '*4)[1]
print(sid)
```

- it splits the output of the `whoami` shell command by lines
- takes the 7th line, splits it at 4 spaces and gets SID string

or even shorter

```
import subprocess    
sid = subprocess.check_output('whoami /User').decode().split('\r\n')[6].split(' '*4)[1]
```

this is for python 3 and windows 10 and may break if Microsoft changed the output of `whoami` in different Windows versions.